# Converting from low to high frequency data, constrained to move in increments

Tags: r, time-series, interpolation

I have data at quarterly frequency in R that I am converting into monthly data using '[tempdisagg](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tempdisagg/tempdisagg.pdf)' package, where the average of the resulting high frequency series is consistent with the low frequency series.

Additionally, I have a constraint such that the monthly data can move only in 25bp increments (the monthly values can only have x.00, x.25, x.50, x.75 as digits). My current approach to implementing the constraint is simply rounding to the nearest 25bp: `output <- round(output / 0.25) * 0.25`

Reproducible example:

```
# converts from low to high frequency series

# need ts object as input
input <- ts(c(1.62, 2.83, 3.85, 4.25, 4.25, 4.25, 4.09, 3.84), frequency = 4, start = c(2022,3))

library(tempdisagg)

output <- predict(td(input ~ 1, conversion = "average", to = "monthly", method = "denton-cholette"))

# round the high-frequency values to the nearest 25bp increment 
output <- round(output / 0.25) * 0.25
```

Input:

```
> input
     Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
2022           1.62 2.83
2023 3.85 4.25 4.25 4.25
2024 4.09 3.84
```

Output:

```
> output
      Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
2022                               1.50 1.50 2.00 2.50 2.75 3.25
2023 3.50 4.00 4.00 4.25 4.25 4.25 4.25 4.25 4.25 4.25 4.25 4.25
2024 4.25 4.00 4.00 4.00 3.75 3.75
```

I am looking for a more precise way to implement the 25bp constraint condition, other than rounding. Any suggestions are welcome.

I've reviewed the documentation for 'tempdisagg' package and couldn't find a way to implement the constraint.
I have also searched the internet for frequency conversions with a constraint (not only in R).

Related question and an excellent answer which I used for my code and also as a template to ask this question (as I am new to all of this)

[Convert from annual to quarterly data, constrained to annual average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764847/convert-from-annual-to-quarterly-data-constrained-to-annual-average)

Comment: Do you mean with: *monthly data can move only in 25bp increments* that `diff(output)` is only between `-0.25` and `0.25`? That the difference between Month is in this range? Or that the monthly values can only have `x.00`, `x.25`, `x.50`, `x.75` as digits? And still consistent with the quarterly data.

Comment: the latter - the monthly values can only have x.00, x.25, x.50, x.75 as digits. Thanks for pointing it out; I have updated my question to make the constraint definition more clear

Comment: In that case, I think your way is good. Is there a need that the quarterly values can be produced with the monthly values?

Comment: not sure what do you mean by "quarterly values can be produced with the monthly values?" There is no other requirement or constraint apart from the ones in the OP.

Comment: Can you give an expected result to see what is meant by *more precise way* .

Comment: I am not sure what the expected result is, and it might be there is no "better" or "precise" (for the lack of a better word) way to implement the constraint than my solution of rounding to the nearest 25bp..

Comment: Thanks. At least I don't know a better way.